# Pentaho - previous week in filename

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

I have the following PDI transformation:

```
Table input --> Select values --> Microsoft Excel writer
```

This transformation fetches previous week data from database and I'd like to save this excel file where filename contains week number. How to insert previous week (2021W40) into filename for Microsoft Excel writer?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution would be to pass the previous week as a parameter to the transformation, this parameter is calculated in a previous transformation with whatever method you prefer:
You can use the table input to use SQL to calculate the previous week, or use the Modified Java Script Value step to use date functions, whichever method suits you best, and then use the Set Variable step to fix the parameter value, afterwards you just pass that value to the following transformation and use it when you fill the file name.